# How to update html path in yeoman angular on build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I've just learning yeoman and grunt. I have created a standard angular project using yeoman-angular generator. I want my folder structures by features instead of by type. for example, i have html in app/products/productlist.html and app/customers/customerlist.html. On build i want this html to be put to dist/templates folder. How can i tell grunt to update the html refs accordingly. Same with images. I put my images in app/assets/images, but on build i want to put it in dist/images folder.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what modules you are using with Grunt. On my Grunt setup, it takes any HTML files in a folder and it's children and moves them over. I would recommend having a structure like 'app/components/<customers/products>/<files>' and setting up your Gruntfile to move any .html files in components over.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to familiarize yourself with Node's core API.

In your case get to know [The File System Module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Here's an example of how you could copy one file from one directory to another.

```
var fs = require('fs'); //load file system module.
//create a writeable stream to your new file.
var out = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, './B/file.js'));
//create a read stream from old file and pipe it to new file.
fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '/A/file.js')).pipe(out);
```

Voila, you're a pro! Now if you want to do something like grab all files ending in `.html`. You'll have to do stuff with `fs.readdir`. Now mind you `fs.readdir` is an `asynchronous` function so the scope of it will not be what you expect. I'm sure you can fiind plenty of info on that topic though.